# Regular Expression for swapping words

Tags: java, regex

I'm a regular expression newbie, and I am unable to figure out how to write a single regular expression that would swap pairs of consecutive words. For example, if the sentence is `"How are you today guys"` then the result should be `"are How today you guys"`

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711587/regex-replace-to-change-the-order-of-words-in-a-sentence

Comment: ('[^']+?')\s+([^"]+?(?>"))$

Comment: Can I do it using replaceAll() function in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to use regex groups, so your regex can be `(\b\w+\b)\s+(\b\w+\b)` so with replaceAll it can be :

```
String str = "How are you today guys";
String regex = "(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s+(\\b\\w+\\b)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, "$2 $1"));
```

Outputs

```
are How today you guys
```

meaning :

- `(\b\w+\b)`  capture first word
- `\s+`        which is followed by a space or more
- `(\b\w+\b)`  capture second word

---

Edit

or like [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898309/regular-expression-for-swapping-words/45898368?noredirect=1#comment78755911_45898368) mention you can use `\\b(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\b` instead, this work fine.

Comment: It works because there are *implicit* word boundaries between `\w` and `\s` and `\s` and `\w`. Actually, word boundaries and zero width assertions in general are usually put outside of groups, so `"\\b(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\b"` should be best here.

Comment: this is the expert, your analysis is really good @WiktorStribiżew for that i like your answers